# why width and height of image is not able to get in php

Tags: php, image, amazon-s3, image-uploading

i am uploading image to s3 server and by php i am making a copy of that image on server ,
if i upload an image of 2.3 mb than the width of image is not coming but if i upload less size image like 26kb than it is showing the width of image so it is able to create the copy .

here is my code of php :

```
$s3 = new S3(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey);

        $thumbId = uniqid();
        $thumbId .= ".jpg"; 
        $img = '';

        if($imgType == "image/jpeg"){
            $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($sourceUrl);
        }else if($imgType == "image/png"){
            $img = imagecreatefrompng($sourceUrl);
        }else if($imgType == "image/gif"){
            $img = imagecreatefromgif($sourceUrl);
        }else{
            $img = imagejpeg($sourceUrl);
        }

    echo    $width = imagesx( $img );
        echo $height = imagesy( $img );
```

please tell me what is the problem with size of image..

regards

rahul

Comment: `than the width of image is not coming` your script is probably crashing due to memory issues. Enable `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to find out for sure

Comment: @Pekka no memory issue i have tried error reporting

Comment: @Rahul what exactly happens? What do you get for $width and $height?

Comment: @Rahul also try  `ini_set('display_errors', true);`

Comment: their should be other issue.Because i already work this type of script and working fine for more than 2 md image.Could you pls check you GD library version?pls use gd2.

Comment: @riad i am using gd library version 2 and higher

Comment: @Rahul please to a `echo "test";` at the end of the script. Does it get shown for the large image?

Comment: @Pekka yeah it is shown for larger image

Comment: @Rahul it is always shown, but `$width` and `$height` are empty?

Comment: @Rahul what does a `echo error_get_last();` at the end of the script show? (If it's PHP >= 5.2)

Comment: @Pekka no error is coming by this also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can be wrong, but I am fairly sure this is a memory issue that doesn't get displayed because some aspect of error reporting is turned off.

Either that, or the 2.3 MB image is broken or in a format that GD can't read - make sure you try it with various images.

If it's a memory issue, here is a related question.

- [PHP GD Allowed memory size exhausted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827908/php-gd-allowed-memory-size-exhausted)

Comment: i have tried less than 1024 kb that is wokring fine and php.ini memory limit is 160M -- then what may be the  problem

Comment: @Rahul what physical dimensions do the image files have? The file size is irrelevant with JPG, the width x height is important. Also, you are still not telling *what* happens exactly. What values go you get with a large image?

Comment: blank values are coming with big images

Comment: the big image 2.3 mb  is of size 1024x768 and small image of 0.9 mb is 4351x3000

Comment: @Rahul what does "blank values" mean exactly. Is anything output at all? What happens if you add a `echo "test";`? Did you try my `ini_set` suggestion from above?

Comment: yeah i have tried ini_set('display_errors', true) also  no error comes

Answer (score 1):

Read this link: [PHP rebuilding images: memory usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092404/php-rebuilding-images-memory-usage)

As riky said, set the memory limit higher if you can. Also realize that the dimensions are more important than the file size (as the file size is for a compressed image). When you open an image in GD, every pixel gets 3-4 bytes allocated to it, RGB and possibly A. Thus, your 4912px x 3264px image needs to use 48,098,304 to 64,131,072 bytes of memory, plus there is overhead and any other memory your script is using.