# php image copy/crop/resize memory limits

Tags: php, image-processing, gd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP rebuilding images: memory usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092404/php-rebuilding-images-memory-usage)

I have a simple image upload script. A user is allowed to upload an image (gif,jpg or png) with a max file size of 10MB. The user is also allowed to apply a crop to
the image, so I set the memory limit on the script to 256MB. I figured 256MB was more then enough memory to crop a 10MB image. I was wrong. 
When a user uploads a large image (around 5000x5000) and barely crops it, the script always throws an out of memory error. I found [this neat tool](http://www.dotsamazing.com/en/labs/phpmemorylimit) to help determine the memory limit when resizing an image with php. I also came across this formula

```
$width * $height * $channels * 1.7
```

to determine how much memory an image will require. I am looking for someone to explain what is going on here. It is pretty clear to me that a 10MB jpeg
is not 10MB when loaded into memory, but how can I determine how much memory it will take up? Is the formula above correct? And is there a more efficent way to crop large images
or do I have to use massive amounts of memory?

For anyone interested, here is the code to crop an image.

```
function myCropImage(&$src, $x, $y, $width, $height) {
    $src_width = imagesx($src);
    $src_height = imagesy($src);

    $max_dst_width = 1024;
    $dst_width = $width;

    $dst_height = $height;
    $max_dst_height = 768;

    // added to restrict size of output image.
    // without this check an out of memory error is thrown.
    if($dst_width > $max_dst_width || $dst_height > $max_dst_height) {
        $scale = min($max_dst_width / $dst_width, $max_dst_height  / $dst_height);
        $dst_width *= $scale;
        $dst_height *= $scale;
    }

    if($x < 0) {
        $width += $x;
        $x = 0;
    }
    if($y < 0) {
        $height += $y;
        $y = 0;
    }

    if (($x + $width) > $src_width) {
        $width = $src_width - $x;
    }

    if (($y + $height) > $src_height) {
        $height = $src_height - $y;
    }

    $temp = imagecreatetruecolor($dst_width, $dst_height);
    imagesavealpha($temp, true);
    imagefill($temp, 0, 0, imagecolorallocatealpha($temp, 0, 0, 0, 127));
    imagecopyresized($temp, $src, 0, 0, $x, $y, $dst_width, $dst_height, $width, $height);

    return $temp;
}
```

Comment: Remember a JPEG is a compressed format, it has to be converted back to a raw form in order to be processed, which is at least the number of pixels in the image x the bits per pixel (32 for RGB + alpha = 4 bytes).  There is a lot of overhead as well due to the internal structure in PHP, hence the need for that scale factor cludge.  It is only a rough estimate.